# problems with show & hide javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, class, hide, show

I have a peculiar situation happening with my show hide function,
this is my code :

```
function expandedFunction(e) {
        var $content = $(".expanded").hide();
        $(".stylistbutton").on("click", function(e){
            $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
            $content.toggle();
        });
}
```

with this code being the call to action:

```
<div>
    <table>
    <tr><td width="15%">
    </td><td width="55%">

    <label for="advanced">Advanced Settings?</label></td><td width="15%">
<input class="stylistbutton" type="button" onClick="expandedFunction(event)" value="+">

    </td><td width="15%">
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I then have my expand/collapse boxes with the class="expanded".

Now for the question.

The function works, It will expand and collapse. However, when I click the button to expand the first two times it doesn't do anything, then it will open, close, then when it next opens it loses the button so I can no longer show and hide my toggled classes.

Can anyone explain why it is not opening when I click it the first few times, then can you explain why the button disappears, then lastly if you could help me fix the problem you would have made my day a lot more worthwhile!

Comment: Try to edit line where you state $(this).toggle.... with $('.expanded').toggle... and tell me if it was enough. Cause I think that the class itself hides also your button. And there is no need to toggle the class on button.

Comment: Every time you click it binds another click event! That is why binding events like this is a bad idea. If you have the click event already inline, why would you attach another?

Comment: Why are you using an onclick inside a function?

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div>
    <table>
    <tr><td width="15%">
    </td><td width="55%">

    <label for="advanced">Advanced Settings?</label></td><td width="15%">
<input class="stylistbutton" type="button" value="+">

    </td><td width="15%">
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".stylistbutton").click(function(){
    $(".expanded").toggle();
  });
});
```

And remeber to set `expanded` class style to `display: none;` at start. Isn't it a better solution? :)

Comment: Thanks, I mixed this with some code a friend helped on and it works a charm. Simple really once you see it done!